# [ROS2]missing <buildtool_depend>ament_python</buildtool_depend> in package.xml

Tags: ros, python, ros2, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed the tutorial:[Creating your first ROS 2 package](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Creating-Your-First-ROS2-Package/)
I entered the following command in my terminal:

```
ros2 pkg create --build-type ament_python test_pkg_py
```

I opened `package.xml`that `ros2 pkg create` automatically generated:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>pubsub_py</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>TODO: Package description</description>
  <maintainer email="sylvia@todo.todo">sylvia</maintainer>
  <license>TODO: License declaration</license>

  <test_depend>ament_copyright</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_flake8</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_pep257</test_depend>
  <test_depend>python3-pytest</test_depend>

  <export>
    <build_type>ament_python</build_type>
  </export>
</package>
```

The content is different from tutorial:[Creating your first ROS 2 package](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Creating-Your-First-ROS2-Package/)
My `package.xml` misses the following command:

```
<buildtool_depend>ament_python</buildtool_depend>
```

Did I miss any dependecies?
ROS environment: Foxy
OS: Ubuntu20.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358703/%5Bros2%5Dmissing-%3Cbuildtool_depend%3Eament_python%3C/buildtool_depend%3E-in-package.xml/) by [sylvia20](https://answers.ros.org/users/57354/sylvia20/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2020-08-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No. According to https://github.com/ros2/ros2_documentation/issues/508 you are fine. (Actually `rosdep install ...` fails if you would have the <buildtool_depend> specified

---

Originally posted by [ipa-jba](https://answers.ros.org/users/3541/ipa-jba/) with karma: 153 on 2020-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0